# Before update hook not being called for DataMapper model with dm 1.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datamapper

I've the following model and I want to execute a method on save and update, problem is that the hook is not being executed on update.

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource
  include BCrypt

  property :id,               Serial
  property :email,            String, :index => true
  property :crypted_password, String, :accessor => :private
  ...

  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

  before :save,   :encrypt_password!

  # also tried the following with no success:
  # before :update, :encrypt_password!

  # and tried this but hell was never raised
  # before :update do
  #  raise 'hell'
  # end

  def encrypt_password!
    self.crypted_password = Password.create password
  end
end
```

This spec fails:

```
  it  'should call encrypt_password! on update' do
    subject.save.should be_true
    subject.should_receive(:encrypt_password!) 
    subject.update(:password => 'other-password', :password_confirmation => 'other-password').should be_true
  end
```

And this passes:

```
  it  'should call encrypt_password! on create' do
    subject.should_receive(:encrypt_password!) 
    subject.save.should be_true
  end
```

I've also tried with after :update in addition to after :save with no success.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug with datamapper but there are a couple of things that you could do to get around it until they fix the problem.

You could override the save method in your User class and then call then necessary encrypt_password! method from within your custom save method. Then simply call the parent's save method to perform the datamapper db save.

Your save method could look like this

```
def save
  encrypt_password!
  super
end
```

I know this violates the aspect-oriented design approach that datamapper has using hook but this will allow you to get your project done now if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late, but I don't think this is a bug. The **create** and **save** hooks will only be called if a resource is valid. You want to change your `before :save, :encrypt_password!` to:

```
before :valid?, :encrypt_password!
```